# ElException when migrating from tomcat 8.0 to 8.5

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, tomcat8.5

We are currently migrating our apps from tomcat 8.0 to tomcat 8.5.

In these apps, we have a very simple spring JEE app which uses JSPs and spring controllers.

When deployed on a Tomcat 8.0, the jsp pages are correctly served, while it produces an error on tomcat 8.5 :

```
javax.el.ELException: The class [com.orange.gvw.acd.controllers.ApiConnectionController] could not be imported as it could not be found
javax.el.ImportHandler.importClass(ImportHandler.java:114)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.getELContext(PageContextImpl.java:962)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:935)
org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.manageConnections_jsp._jspService(manageConnections_jsp.java:192)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:443)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1243)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:965)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:856)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:841)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

We found out that this issue happens when our jsp page is including an el, e.g. ${toto}. When we remove this el, it works.

Is there something to be fixed or configured in order to serve jsp that includes el ?

Comment: The message is explicit: the class com.orange.gvw.acd.controllers.ApiConnectionController was not found.

Comment: True, but the fact is that this controller is actually loaded and can be found.
Moreover, when we are using a jsp without el in it, no error is thrown concerning the controller ApiConnectionController.

Answer (score 0):

Answering to myself, the issue was on the platform side : We had the package libservlet3.1-java version 8.0.14-1+deb8u11 installed, whereas the version 8.5.14-1~bpo8+1 was required for tomcat 8.5.